# A question about ergodic processes - 'global' vs 'local'

Tags: probability, ergodic

I have a question regarding the ergodicity of a transformation.

Given a probability space,

$(X,\Sigma,\mu,T_{N})$

where,

$({T_{N})}_{n\geqslant 0}$

And T is some ordered transformation through time. Then for ergodicity to hold we require,

$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^{n}(x)) = \int f(x)$

Which implies that $\mu(T^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A) $, where $ A \subseteq \Sigma $.  In consequence, if we can demonstrate that  $\mu(T^{-1}(A)) \neq \mu(A) $, then $T_N$ is presumably not ergodic. Question one: is this true?

Question two is based on the following reservation. If what I say above is true, a legitimate criticism (in my view) could be the following. That is, we don't often actually seen $T_N$ but rather, say, $T_j$,  whereby $0 < j < N$. In which case (hypothetically at least) one could argue that the process in question *could* still be ergodic if it were left to 'run' longer, given that the process may then converge as required. Because  all we need for ergodicity to apply is that,

$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(T^{n}(x)) = \int f(x)$

Not,

$\frac{1}{j} \sum_{i=0}^{j-1}f(T^{j}(x)) = \int f(x)$

Is this valid reasoning?

In advance, many thanks.

Comment: Huh? The definition of ergodicity is $\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ implies $\mu(A)=0$ or $\mu(A)=1$.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your reply. Would you mind expanding on your comment somewhat.